# How to use SKMaps OneBoxSearch and several thing?

Tags: ios, swift, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I have a question about using SKMaps 'OneBoxSearch'.

I referred  site http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios here.

But when I did 'Integrating 3rd party providers' part, I couldn't find "SKOBaseSearchObject". Am I do Something wrong?

I'm so wonder about that.

Of course, SKMaps support demo project, but there is no "SKOBaseSearchObject".

What can I do for this?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Have you integrated SKOSearchLib into your project? You can find the steps here: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec25_2

Comment: yes I did it..Thanks, I think I need to spend more time!

Comment: I missed something. I solved.